# How to find the parents in this data structure in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm

We have a data structure where each item stores -- among other things -- its depth. Its parent the closest previous item which has a smaller depth: To show an example:

```
A:depth 0
B:depth 1
C:depth 1
D:depth 2
E:depth 1
F:depth 2
G:depth 0
H:depth 1
I:depth 1
```

The parents in this case is

- A: root
- B: A
- C: A
- D: C
- E: A
- F: E
- G: root
- H: G
- J: G

My code is:

```
<?php
  function parentItems(\ArrayAccess|\Traversable $items, object $root_object): \SplObjectStorage {
    $parent_stack =  new \SplStack();
    $parent_items = new \SplObjectStorage();
    // The tree starts with the root.
    $previous_item = $root_object;
    // Top level items have a depth of 0 and the root needs to be even less
    // deep.
    $previous_depth = -1;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
      $depth = (int) $item->getDepth();
      // if the current depth is higher than the previous one then the
      // previous item is the current parent.
      if ($depth > $previous_depth) {
        $parent_stack->push($previous_item);
      }
      // On the other hand, if the current element is less deep than the
      // previous one, then the previous parents are no longer needed.
      elseif ($depth < $previous_depth) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $previous_depth - $depth; $i++) {
          $parent_stack->pop();
        }
      }
      // At this point, the stack top contains the current parent.
      $parent_items[$item] = $parent_stack->top();
      $previous_depth = $depth;
      $previous_item = $item;
    }
    return $parent_items;
  }
// Example dataset
$depths = [0,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,1,1,0,1,2,0,0,0,1,2,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,2,2,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,2,3,3,0,0,0,];
$a = new ArrayObject();
foreach ($depths as $depth) {
  $a[] = new class($depth) {
    protected $depth;
    function __construct($depth) { $this->depth = $depth; }
    function getDepth() { return $this->depth; }
  };
}
parentItems($a);
?>
```

While this looks relatively straightforward and it does work, keeping the previous item around makes me unhappy, not quite sure why, but it feels wrong. Could we do without it? While arrays have `prev()` iterators AFAIK do not.

Comment: Looks like a question for codereview.stackexchange.com, not here

Comment: I actually started posting there then decided against it because it might depend on what PHP has available, don't you think so?

Comment: `foreach ($items as $item)` this is iterating the object itself. To access data through `ArrayAccess` interface you should use `offsetGet` method.

Comment: Added a note it's also `Traversable`.

Comment: Providing a *usable* dataset would be also a wise move. So one trying to write the code for you won't have to write the dataset to toy with.

Comment: Sure thing, pulled a dataset from the database and mocked an object around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, ok, for that case I have another idea. We can use `depth` as index to array `$lastItemsByDepth`, because the parent of the item is the last item with the `depth-1` so we keep it in the `$lastItemsByDepth` array and access it by the items depth. And rewrite previous array element or add new one every step. So, maybe  my answer is not correct, because OP wanted not to keep the previous item, but here we are keeping an item to every depth. But this solution seems to be more simple.

```
$parentForDepth [0] = $root_object;

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $depth = (int)$item->getDepth();
    $parents_items[$item] = $parentForDepth[$depth];
    $parentForDepth[$depth + 1] = $item;
}
```

Comment: I haven't added an example where the depth changes 1-2-1 that's my bad -- but it's possible, you can't count on lower depth meaning root immediately. I am sorry. I will edit the question.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: @chx, I have edited the answer, this loop can find any parent, but maybe it's not the solution you wanted